# How to cast object within a C# System.Linq lambda expression?

Tags: c#

```
List<System.Guid> meshGuidList= new List<System.Guid>();

foreach (TreeGridItem meshcol in TerrainData.MeshCollection)
{
    Globals.MeshProperty meshprop = meshcol.Tag as Globals.MeshProperty;
    meshGuidList.Add(meshprop.MeshGuid);
}
```

I have a collection, in order to access it, I need to cast the items as `TreeGridItem`.

After casting the items, I need to cast `meshcol.Tag` again as `Globals.MeshProperty` so I can access it.

Basically I want a list of `meshprop.MeshGuid` using simple `.Select` function.

But the multiple casting feels a bit difficult.

Comment: What is the problem you have when you use `.Select()`? Please [edit] your question to include your attempts and the problem you have with them.

Comment: You need to show enough code for us to understand the types of you variables  etc. For example, depending on the type of `TerrainData.MeshCollectiom` you may be able to use the `Cast` extension method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what the `Type` is that is returned from the `MeshCollection` enumerator, but this syntax may work for you if all of the items in the collection can be cast to `TreeGridItem`

```
List<System.Guid> meshGuidList = TerrainData.MeshCollection
                     .Cast<TreeGridItem>()
                     .Select(mesh => (mesh.Tag as Globals.MeshProperty).MeshGuid)
                     .ToList();
```

_You could split that `Select` clause out to multiple lines if you wanted, but I'm not sure we gain much in readability or performance:

```
List<System.Guid> meshGuidList = TerrainData.MeshCollection
                     .Cast<TreeGridItem>()
                     .Select(mesh => mesh.Tag)
                     .Cast<Globals.MeshProperty>()
                     .Select(prop => prop.MeshGuid)
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!
This is what I am looking for!
I wasn't very sure how to cast things in Linq. Your answer really does help!